# Joining two queries together in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 queries in Oracle, one gives me information about the jobs, the other gives me a correct (amended) start time and target time to take into account the working day.

The field linking both tables is job.job_number

What I would like to do is have them together so that all the information is provided in one report, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Query 1 code

```
select
job.job_number,
job.job_entry_date,
job.site_code

from
job
inner join JOB_STATUS_LOG on JOB.JOB_NUMBER = JOB_STATUS_LOG.JOB_NUMBER 
and job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join JOB_STATUS on JOB_STATUS.STATUS_CODE = JOB_STATUS_LOG.STATUS_CODE

where
job_status_log.allocated_officer = 'IDVE' 
and job_status.status_code in ('5100','5200','5300','5400')

order by
job.job_number
```

Query 1 output

```
Job Number            Job Entry Date           Job Site Code
12345                 01/08/2019   21:00       1234
67890                 01/08/2019   18:00       5678
```

Query 2 Code

```
select 
job_number, 
clock_start, 

case
when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 2 + 63/24
when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 15/24
else target_time
end as target_time       

from 
(
select job_number, priority_code, clock_start, 
CASE 
WHEN PRIORITY_CODE IN ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07') 
THEN
clock_start + case priority_code 
when 'GC01' then 1 
when 'GC02' then 2 
when 'GC03' then 0.5
when 'GC04' then 1 
when 'GC05' then 2 
when 'GC06' then 4
when 'GC07' then 24
end / 24 
ELSE TARGET_COMP_DATE END as target_time

          from                                                                                                                
          (                                                                                 
          select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, target_comp_date,                                                                                
          case                                                                         
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Fri'                                                                                    
          and floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 80/24
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Sat'
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 56/24
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Sun'
          or floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 32/24
          when floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) < 8
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 8/24
          else job_entry_date
          end as clock_start                                                                                         
          from job                                                                                               
          )

  )

  where
  priority_code in ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07')
```

Query 2 output

```
Job Number            Clock Start              Target Time
12345                 02/08/2019   08:00       02/08/2019   10:00
67890                 02/08/2019   08:00       02/08/2019   12:00
```

Required Output
This is how I would like it to appear

```
Job Number Job Entry Date   Job Site Code Clock Start      Target Time
12345      01/08/2019 21:00 1234          02/08/2019 08:00 02/08/2019 10:00
67890      01/08/2019 18:00 5678          02/08/2019 08:00 02/08/2019 12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use current queries as sources for the `WITH` factoring clause (i.e. the CTE, *Common table expression*) and join them afterwards. I've shortened your queries (named `q1` and `q2`) to make the example simpler to understand:

```
WITH q1 AS (SELECT job_number, job_entry_date, site_code FROM some_tables),
     q2 AS (SELECT job_number, clock_start, target_time FROM another_tables)
SELECT a.job_number,
       a.job_entry_date,
       a.site_code,
       b.clock_start,
       b.target_time
  FROM q1 a JOIN q2 b ON a.job_number = b.job_number
```

---

As you said that the first *word* has to be `SELECT`, no problem - switch to inline views:

```
SELECT a.job_number,
       a.job_entry_date,
       a.site_code,
       b.clock_start,
       b.target_time
  FROM (SELECT job_number, job_entry_date, site_code FROM some_tables) a
       JOIN
       (SELECT job_number, clock_start, target_time FROM another_tables) b
          ON a.job_number = b.job_number
```

I don't know which version it is nor whether it supports such joins; if not, then another option is

```
  ...
  FROM (SELECT job_number, job_entry_date, site_code FROM some_tables) a,
       (SELECT job_number, clock_start, target_time FROM another_tables) b
 WHERE a.job_number = b.job_number
```

Comment: Thanks for this @littlefoot - the version of Oracle I'm using insists on having SELECT as the very first word otherwise it won't run the code :(

Comment: You're welcome. I've added some more options into my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: @RobMorris what version of Oracle are you using? (`SELECT VERSION FROM v$instance;`) Also, what tool are you using to query the database?

Comment: @RobMorris (I ask because subquery factoring (the "with" clause) was added in Oracle 9.2, so to use it your db must be at least 9.2, and your tool to query the database must be at a version that works with Oracle 9.2 or higher.)

Answer (score 0):

As you are basically reading your info's from the `job` table you might simple pass the additional data through your subselects auf `Query 2`. The `JOINS` in `Query 1` are only for filtering reasons i think:

```
select 
job_number, 
job_entry_date, 
site_code, 
clock_start, 

case
when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 2 + 63/24
when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 15/24
else target_time
end as target_time       

from 
(
select job_number, job_entry_date, site_code, priority_code, clock_start, 
CASE 
WHEN PRIORITY_CODE IN ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07') 
THEN
clock_start + case priority_code 
when 'GC01' then 1 
when 'GC02' then 2 
when 'GC03' then 0.5
when 'GC04' then 1 
when 'GC05' then 2 
when 'GC06' then 4
when 'GC07' then 24
end / 24 
ELSE TARGET_COMP_DATE END as target_time

          from                                                                                                                
          (                                                                                 
          select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, target_comp_date,                                                                                
          case                                                                         
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Fri'                                                                                    
          and floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 80/24
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Sat'
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 56/24
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
          'Sun'
          or floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 32/24
          when floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) < 8
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 8/24
          else job_entry_date
          end as clock_start
          ,site_code
          from job                                                                                               
          )

  )

  where
  priority_code in ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07')
```